# React navigation error: Before Calling 'reduxfiyNavigator', please call 'createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware',

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

This is my code so far:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import Rehydration from '../Services/Rehydration'
import ReduxPersist from '../Config/ReduxPersist'
import Config from '../Config/DebugConfig'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
import ScreenTracking from './ScreenTrackingMiddleware'
import { createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware } from 'react-navigation-redux-helpers'

// creates the store
export default (rootReducer, rootSaga) => {
  /* ------------- Redux Configuration ------------- */

  const middleware = []
  const enhancers = []

  /* ------------- Navigation Middleware ------------ */
  const navigationMiddleware = createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware(
    'root',
    state => state.nav
  )
  middleware.push(navigationMiddleware)

  /* ------------- Analytics Middleware ------------- */
  middleware.push(ScreenTracking)

  /* ------------- Saga Middleware ------------- */

  const sagaMonitor = Config.useReactotron ? console.tron.createSagaMonitor() : null
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware({ sagaMonitor })
  middleware.push(sagaMiddleware)

  /* ------------- Assemble Middleware ------------- */

  enhancers.push(applyMiddleware(...middleware))

  // if Reactotron is enabled (default for __DEV__), we'll create the store through Reactotron
  const createAppropriateStore = Config.useReactotron ? console.tron.createStore : createStore
  const store = createAppropriateStore(rootReducer, compose(...enhancers))

  // configure persistStore and check reducer version number
  if (ReduxPersist.active) {
    Rehydration.updateReducers(store)
  }

  // kick off root saga
  let sagasManager = sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)

  return {
    store,
    sagasManager,
    sagaMiddleware
  }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> error:  Before Calling 'reduxfiyNavigator',
>   please call 'createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware', so that we know when to trigger your listener.

I added detailed code [here at GitHUB](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4871).
I'm using the *ignite react native starter kit* called [*androdss*](https://github.com/infinitered/ignite).
I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5):

As per the error, you need to initialize your `createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware` before `reduxfiyNavigator`.

There can be *other alternative approaches*, but here's how I fixed it.

As per the `ignite-cli` `androdss` generator.

### **AppNavigation.js**

Define your `middleware` and wrap the `navigator` to `reduxify` it.

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import LaunchScreen from '../Containers/LaunchScreen'
import { createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware, reduxifyNavigator } from 'react-navigation-redux-helpers'

import styles from './Styles/NavigationStyles'

// Manifest of possible screens
export const PrimaryNav = createStackNavigator({
  LaunchScreen: { screen: LaunchScreen }
}, {
  // Default config for all screens
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'LaunchScreen',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: styles.header
  }
})

// Create middleware and connect
export const appNavigatorMiddleware = createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware(
  'root',
  state => state.nav
);

const AppNavigator = reduxifyNavigator(PrimaryNav, 'root');

export default AppNavigator
```

### **NavigationRedux.js**

Set your router as per `react-navigation`

```
import {PrimaryNav} from '../Navigation/AppNavigation'
export const reducer = (state, action) => {
  const newState = PrimaryNav.router.getStateForAction(action, state)
  return newState || state
}
```

### **ReduxNavigation.js**

Apply the props directly to the component since `addNavigationHelpers` has been removed as *named export* from `react-navigation`

```
import React from 'react'
import { BackHandler, Platform } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import AppNavigation from './AppNavigation'

class ReduxNavigation extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount () {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') return
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
      const { dispatch, nav } = this.props
      // change to whatever is your first screen, otherwise unpredictable results may occur
      if (nav.routes.length === 1 && (nav.routes[0].routeName === 'LaunchScreen')) {
        return false
      }
      // if (shouldCloseApp(nav)) return false
      dispatch({ type: 'Navigation/BACK' })
      return true
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') return
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress')
  }

  render () {
    return <AppNavigation state={this.props.nav}  dispatch={this.props.dispatch}/>
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ nav: state.nav })
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxNavigation)
```

### **CreateStore.js**

Add the export middleware to initialize

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import Rehydration from '../Services/Rehydration'
import ReduxPersist from '../Config/ReduxPersist'
import Config from '../Config/DebugConfig'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
import ScreenTracking from './ScreenTrackingMiddleware'
import {appNavigatorMiddleware} from '../Navigation/AppNavigation'
// creates the store
export default (rootReducer, rootSaga) => {
  /* ------------- Redux Configuration ------------- */

  const middleware = []
  const enhancers = []

  /* ------------- Navigation Middleware ------------ */
  middleware.push(appNavigatorMiddleware)

  /* ------------- Analytics Middleware ------------- */
  middleware.push(ScreenTracking)

  /* ------------- Saga Middleware ------------- */

  const sagaMonitor = Config.useReactotron ? console.tron.createSagaMonitor() : null
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware({ sagaMonitor })
  middleware.push(sagaMiddleware)

  /* ------------- Assemble Middleware ------------- */

  enhancers.push(applyMiddleware(...middleware))

  // if Reactotron is enabled (default for __DEV__), we'll create the store through Reactotron
  const createAppropriateStore = Config.useReactotron ? console.tron.createStore : createStore
  const store = createAppropriateStore(rootReducer, compose(...enhancers))

  // configure persistStore and check reducer version number
  if (ReduxPersist.active) {
    Rehydration.updateReducers(store)
  }

  // kick off root saga
  let sagasManager = sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)

  return {
    store,
    sagasManager,
    sagaMiddleware
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you check two things:

1) The second argument to `reduxifyNavigator` is the same as the first argument to `createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware`, i.e. `root`. Also, I recommend moving all constants to a separate file, e.g. 'constants.js', and importing their definitions to use in your code. It eliminates the possibility of such errors.

2) Trace the order of imports in your app starting from your root source file and make sure that you import your store before your navigation, otherwise `reduxifyNavigator` will be called before `createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware` and that will trigger this error.